# Changing the format of all cells in a datagridview to combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a few data tables. I loop through the number of datatables that I have. In the loop I create a DataGridView with the datasource being the given Data Table at that index. How can I then change the columns to be of type Combobox? I know how to do this on the designer but what about programatically? I've tried:

```
For each column as DataGridViewColumn in table.Columns
  column.CellType = DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Next
```

Obviously this doesn't work. CellType is a read only property and I cannot simply set it equal to a class type. I know this is probably simple, I know I am stupid. Please help.

Comment: You can build the data grid manually instead of allowing the data source to autogenerate columns. But, how do you expect to populate the comboboxes with data?

Comment: There are enumerations associated with each column. I will define the enums as array's and then add each enum to the combobox items

Comment: If you want your CBO column to do something like show the Enum "name" but return the value to your code, each CBO col needs a datasource, not just some stuff added to the items collection.

Comment: [Here is some code](https://github.com/crowcoder/FruitCSharp/blob/master/FruitCSharp/FruitEditForm.cs) that builds a datagridview programmatically(GridSetup method) if you need something to get you started.

Comment: @Crowcoder You should post an example in VB.NET since the OP's code is in VB. Trowing some C# is not helping the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define an entire column as a combo box. See my example where you have a definition for a combobox with the same value for every rows. I also included a way for you to only replace a single cell with a combobox. See how the "people" column is a textboxcolumn where I put a combobox instead. It also shows you how to assign values and set the default value. It's the same concept for a checkbox column/cell.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim NewCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = "ID", .HeaderText = "ID"})
        With NewCol
            .Name = "ComboBoxCol"
            .HeaderText = "Language"
            .Items.Add("VB.NET")
            .Items.Add("C#")
            .Items.Add("F#")
            .DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = .Items(0)
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(NewCol)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = "PeopleCol", .HeaderText = "People"})
        Dim xRow As String() = {"1"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(xRow)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add({"2"})
        DataGridView1(1, 0).Value = "C#"
        Dim xPeople1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        With xPeople1
            .Items.Add("Santa")
            .Items.Add("Satan")
            .Value = .Items(0)
        End With
        DataGridView1(2, 0) = xPeople1

        Dim xPeople2 As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        With xPeople2
            .Items.Add("God")
            .Items.Add("Allah")
            .Value = .Items(1)
        End With
        DataGridView1(2, 1) = xPeople2
    End Sub
End Class
```